# Como capturar a extensão de um arquivo no R

Tags: r

Estou com dificuldade para capturar a extensão dos arquivos importados.

Gostaria de extrair a extensão do arquivo e armazenar em uma variável.

```
arquivo <- "dados/Inscritos.xls"
extensao <- ?
```

Answer (score 4):

Esta função utiliza `basename` para ficar com os nomes de ficheiros sem os diretórios. Depois verifica se os nomes de ficheiros têm um ponto ou não. Finalmente, extrai só o que está entre o último ponto `"."` e o fim dos nomes de ficheiros.

```
extensao <- function(x){
  x <- basename(x)
  y <- character(length(x))
  i <- grep("\\.", x)
  y[i] <- sub("^.*\\.(.*$)", "\\1", x[i])
  y
}

extensao(arquivo)
#[1] "xls"

fls <- list.files(full.names = TRUE)
fls <- fls[!file.info(fls)$isdir]
extensao(fls)
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar regex através do pacote `stringr`

- O parênteses define a parte da extração do texto
- \w+ define que é uma palavra
- $ define que é no final da string

```
    library(stringr)
    arquivo <- "dados/Inscritos.xls"
    extensao <- str_extract(arquivo, '(\\w+)$')
```

Answer (score 2):

Com o R base, dá pra usar a função `strsplit`:

```
arquivo <- "dados/Inscritos.xls"
extensao <- unlist(strsplit(arquivo, split = "\\."))[2]
```

Como o resultado de `strsplit` é uma lista, é necessário transformá-la em vetor através do comando `unlist` e aí retirar o segundo elemento desse vetor.

Comment: Pensei nesta solução, mas é sempre possível ter mais de um ponto nos arquivos.

Comment: Verdade. Não me dei conta disso.